# Weak lower semicontinuity property of a bounded, coercive and linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

Let $A\colon V \to V^*$ be a bounded linear coercive operator on a Hilbert space $V$.

Does it follow that for if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $V$ (weak convergence) then
$$\langle Au, u \rangle \leq \liminf \langle Au_n, u_n \rangle?$$

This is somehow related to weak lower semicontinuity of norms..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By coercivity:
$$0\le\langle A(u_n-u),u_n-u\rangle = \langle A(u_n),u_n\rangle-\langle A(u_n),u\rangle-\langle A(u),u_n\rangle+\langle A(u),u\rangle$$
So:
$$\langle A(u_n),u\rangle+\langle A(u),u_n\rangle-\langle A(u),u\rangle\le\langle A(u_n),u_n\rangle.$$
Now, $A$ is continuous, so by $u_n\rightharpoonup u $ it follows that $\langle A(u_n),u \rangle  \rightarrow \langle A(u),u\rangle$ and $\langle A(u),u_n\rangle\rightarrow \langle A(u),u\rangle$. Then:
$$\langle A(u_n),u\rangle+\langle A(u),u_n\rangle-\langle A(u),u\rangle\rightarrow \langle A(u),u\rangle, n\rightarrow\infty.$$
Then:
$$\langle A(u),u\rangle=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\langle A(u_n),u\rangle+\langle A(u),u_n\rangle-\langle A(u),u\rangle\right) \le \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle A(u_n),u_n\rangle$$